# Creating a Thread Queue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to handle user request one by one(similar like a queue job)

This is what i have:

```
Thread checkQueue;
Boolean IsComplete = true;

protected void Start()
{
    checkQueue = new Thread(CheckQueueState);
    checkQueue.Start();    
}

private void CheckQueueState()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (checkIsComplete)
            {
                ContinueDoSomething();

                checkQueue.Abort();
                break;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

protected void ContinueDoSomething()
{
    IsComplete = false;
    ...
    ...
    IsComplete = true; //when done, set it to true
}
```

Everytime when there is a new request from user, system will call `Start()` function and check whether the previous job is complete, if yes then will proceed to next job.

But I am not sure whether it is correct to do in this way.

Any improvement or any better way to do this?

Comment: You effectively cannot use Thread.Abort. Search on SO to find some discussions about why.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in ASP.NET?   It sounds like something that runs at the server and runs independently of client browsers.

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, this is a standalone application and run at server

Comment: Can you describe a little more what you are doing please? I understand it like this: A user clicks a button and triggers a "request". You want requests to be processed one-after-the-other. Is that accurate and complete? Does the user wait for completion or not?

Comment: FYI:  I removed the asp.net tag (and added C#)

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to have a `BlockingCollection<T>` and a thread looping through jobs yielded by `GetConsumingEnumerable()` (or returned by `Take()`) and processing them sequentially. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx for an example. It's extremely simple and pretty much bulletproof. The only downside is that the thread will potentially spend a lot of time being blocked - however that tends not to be a huge issue in most scenarios.

Comment: You can also use a Queue<T> Class and Peek/Dequeue and do your operation.. I don't see a reason why you need a thread unless you have a disk I/O or other non-cpu operations being done inside the ContinueDoSomething.

Comment: @usr Yes, correct. User no need to wait for completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like usr's suggestion regarding using TPL Dataflow. If you have the ability to add external dependencies to your project (TPL Dataflow is not distributed as part of the .NET framework), then it provides a clean solution to your problem.

If, however, you're stuck with what the framework has to offer, you should have a look at `BlockingCollection<T>`, which works nicely with the producer-consumer pattern that you're trying to implement.

I've thrown together a quick .NET 4.0 example to illustrate how it can be used in your scenario. It is not very lean because it has a lot of calls to `Console.WriteLine()`. However, if you take out all the clutter it's extremely simple.

At the center of it is a `BlockingCollection<Action>`, which gets `Action` delegates added to it from any thread, and a thread specifically dedicated to dequeuing and executing those `Action`s sequentially in the exact order in which they were added.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SimpleProducerConsumer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread id is {0}.", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            using (var blockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<Action>())
            {
                // Start our processing loop.
                var actionLoop = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Starting action loop on thread {0} (dedicated action loop thread).",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                        Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread);

                    // Dequeue actions as they become available.
                    foreach (var action in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        // Invoke the action synchronously
                        // on the "actionLoop" thread.
                        action();
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Action loop terminating.");
                });

                actionLoop.Start();

                // Enqueue some work.
                Console.WriteLine("Enqueueing action 1 from thread {0} (main thread).", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                blockingCollection.Add(() => SimulateWork(1));

                Console.WriteLine("Enqueueing action 2 from thread {0} (main thread).", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                blockingCollection.Add(() => SimulateWork(2));

                // Let's enqueue it from another thread just for fun.
                var enqueueTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "Enqueueing action 3 from thread {0} (task executing on a thread pool thread).",
                        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

                    blockingCollection.Add(() => SimulateWork(3));
                });

                // We have to wait for the task to complete
                // because otherwise we'll end up calling
                // CompleteAdding before our background task
                // has had the chance to enqueue action #3.
                enqueueTask.Wait();

                // Tell our loop (and, consequently, the "actionLoop" thread)
                // to terminate when it's done processing pending actions.
                blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();

                Console.WriteLine("Done enqueueing work. Waiting for the loop to complete.");

                // Block until the "actionLoop" thread terminates.
                actionLoop.Join();

                Console.WriteLine("Done. Press Enter to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void SimulateWork(int actionNo)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Finished processing action {0} on thread {1} (dedicated action loop thread).", actionNo, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
0.016s: Main thread id is 10.
0.025s: Enqueueing action 1 from thread 10 (main thread).
0.026s: Enqueueing action 2 from thread 10 (main thread).
0.027s: Starting action loop on thread 11 (dedicated action loop thread).
0.028s: Enqueueing action 3 from thread 6 (task executing on a thread pool thread).
0.028s: Done enqueueing work. Waiting for the loop to complete.
0.527s: Finished processing action 1 on thread 11 (dedicated action loop thread).
1.028s: Finished processing action 2 on thread 11 (dedicated action loop thread).
1.529s: Finished processing action 3 on thread 11 (dedicated action loop thread).
1.530s: Action loop terminating.
1.532s: Done. Press Enter to quit.
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. One of the requirements is, it has to be execute one-after-the-other(it might take up 30 seconds  to complete each task). How can i make sure the current task is completed before the next task start?

Comment: @My2ndLovE, I was aware of that requirement. I've prefixed output lines with a timestamp so that you can see that the queued jobs are in fact executed sequentially (each one takes ~500ms).

Your use of the word "task" has confused me a bit though. *Are* you using `Task`s to encapsulate your work? Because if you are then using `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`'s `ExclusiveScheduler` would be better way of going about the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ActionBlock<T>` from the TPL Dataflow library. Set its MaxDegreeOfParalellism to 1 and you're done.

Note, that ASP.NET worker processes can recycle at any time (e.g. due to scheduled recycle, memory limit, server reboot or deployment), so the queued work might suddenly be lost without notice. I recommend you look into some external queueing solution like MSMQ (or others) for reliable queues.

Comment: ActionBlock need to run at .net framework 4.5? I am using vs2010

Comment: It is available as a library for a long time now. It requires at most 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Reactive Extensions from Microsoft. This library contains a set of schedulers available that follow the semantics you require.

The best to fit your needs is the `EventLoopScheduler`. It will queue up actions and perform them one after another. If it completes an action and there are more items in the queue it will sequentially process the actions on the same thread until the queue is empty and then it disposes the thread. When a new action is queued it creates a new thread. It is very efficient because of this.

The code is super simple and looks like this:

```
var scheduler = new System.Reactive.Concurrency.EventLoopScheduler();

scheduler.Schedule(() => { /* action here */ });
```

If you need to have every queued action performed on a new thread then use it like this:

```
var scheduler = new System.Reactive.Concurrency.NewThreadScheduler();

scheduler.Schedule(() => { /* action here */ });
```

Very simple.